# Grid: Two areas are not coming side by side

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I'm just trying to fit two areas together side by side like this:

[image]

but I am getting this:

[image]

I  understand grids like by looking through w3schools and I try doing their examples of it but I still can't get it and I don't know why. Can someone please help me with this and also just roughly explain me grids. I tried watching Youtube videos and I almost get it, for example I know its kind of the same concept as tables in html.

Also code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        body {
        display:grid;
        grid-template: 1fr 2fr;
        grid-gap: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
        }
        table,td,th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        th {
            background-color:black;
            color:white;
            font-family:verdana;
        }
        .time {
            background-color:#D3D3D3
        }
        .button {
            border:0;
            background:transparent;
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-weight:bold;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        td {
            font-family:Calibri;
        }
        table {
            display:inline-block;
        }
        form {
            display:inline-block;
            float:right;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1> Soccer Camp Registration</h1>
    </header>
<div class="gridcontainer">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="times">
        <colspan = "7">
    </colgroup>
    <div class="tables">
    <table>
        <tr class="days">
            <th></th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">9:00 am-10:30am</td>
            <td>Free Time</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Technical Skills</td>
            <td colspan="4">Training Session</td>
            <td>Free Time</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">10:30 am-12:00pm</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Round Robin Games</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">Dribbling</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Game Analysis</td>
            <td> Agility</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">1:00pm-2:30pm</td>
            <td>Strength Training</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">2:30pm-5:00pm</td>
            <td colspan="3">Nutrition</td>
            <td>Passing and Receiving</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">Campers Choice</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">6:00pm-8:00pm</td>
            <td colspan="5"> Night Games</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <caption>July 2017 Weekly Schedule</caption>
    <div class="forms">
    <form method="POST" action="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/showit.pl">
        <h2> Request Camp Information</h2>
        <fieldset class="camplc">
            <legend for="camplc"> Camper Location</legend>
            <label for="province"> Province</label>
            <select name="province" id="province">
                <option value="BC"> British Columbia</option>
                <option value="ON" >Ontario</option>
                <option value="AB" >ALberta</option>
                <option value="QC" >Quebec</option>
                <option value="YK" > Yukon</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="campid">
            <legend for="campid"> Camper Identification</legend>
            <label for="firstname"> First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fn">
            <br>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="ln"> 
            <br>
            <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" id="male">
                <label for="male"> Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" id="female">
                <label for="female">Female</label>
            <br>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
            <br>
            <label for="age">Camper Age</label>
            <select name="age" form="age">
                <option value="8">8-9</option>
                <option value="10" >10-12</option>
                <option value="13" >13-15</option>
                <option value="16" >16-19</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="info">
            <legend for="info"> Please Send me information about</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Camp Dates" id="cd">
            <label for="campdates"> Camp Dates</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Camp Fees" id="cf">
            <label for="campdates"> Camp Fees</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Transportation" id="tn">
            <label for="campdates">Transportation</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="questions">
            <legend for="questions"> Question?</legend>
            <textarea placeholder="Please enter any questions or comments here" rows ="5" cols="50"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Request Info" class="button">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="button">
    </form>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code this is exactly as you gave your image hope it will work for you.

```css
   body {
/*     display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr; */
}
header { text-align: center;}
table,td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: verdana;
  padding: 25px 67px;
}
.time { background-color:#D3D3D3 }
.button {
  border: 0;
  background:transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
td {
  font-family: Calibri;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
table { display: inline-block; }
form {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #262626;
  /* float:right; */
}
.gridcontainer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    border: 2px solid #262626;
}
fieldset.camplc { padding: 20px 100px; }
fieldset.campid { padding: 10px 90px; }
fieldset.info { padding: 10px 85px; }
fieldset.questions { padding: 10px 90px; }
```

```html
   <header>
        <h1> Soccer Camp Registration</h1>
    </header>
<div class="gridcontainer">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="times">
        <colspan = "6">
<!--     </colgroup> -->
    <div class="tables">
    <table>
        <tr class="days">
            <th></th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">9:00 am-10:30am</td>
            <td>Free Time</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Technical Skills</td>
            <td colspan="4">Training Session</td>
            <td>Free Time</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">10:30 am-12:00pm</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Round Robin Games</td>
            <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">Dribbling</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Game Analysis</td>
            <td> Agility</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">1:00pm-2:30pm</td>
            <td>Strength Training</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">2:30pm-5:00pm</td>
            <td colspan="3">Nutrition</td>
            <td>Passing and Receiving</td>
            <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">Campers Choice</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="time">6:00pm-8:00pm</td>
            <td colspan="5"> Night Games</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
      
    <caption>July 2017 Weekly Schedule</caption>
         </colspan>
     </colgroup>
   
<!-- <!--     <colgroup> -->
        <col class="times"> 
        <colspan = "4">
    </colgroup>
    <div class="forms">
    <form method="POST" action="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/showit.pl">
        <h2> Request Camp Information</h2>
        <fieldset class="camplc">
            <legend for="camplc"> Camper Location</legend>
            <label for="province"> Province</label>
            <select name="province" id="province">
                <option value="BC"> British Columbia</option>
                <option value="ON" >Ontario</option>
                <option value="AB" >ALberta</option>
                <option value="QC" >Quebec</option>
                <option value="YK" > Yukon</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="campid">
            <legend for="campid"> Camper Identification</legend>
            <label for="firstname"> First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fn">
            <br>
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="ln"> 
            <br>
            <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" id="male">
                <label for="male"> Male</label>
            <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" id="female">
                <label for="female">Female</label>
            <br>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
            <br>
            <label for="age">Camper Age</label>
            <select name="age" form="age">
                <option value="8">8-9</option>
                <option value="10" >10-12</option>
                <option value="13" >13-15</option>
                <option value="16" >16-19</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="info">
            <legend for="info"> Please Send me information about</legend>
            <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Camp Dates" id="cd">
            <label for="campdates"> Camp Dates</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Camp Fees" id="cf">
            <label for="campdates"> Camp Fees</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Transportation" id="tn">
            <label for="campdates">Transportation</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="questions">
            <legend for="questions"> Question?</legend>
            <textarea placeholder="Please enter any questions or comments here" rows ="5" cols="50"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Request Info" class="button">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="button">
    </form>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation and follow tutorials carefully. Even W3schools has nice tutorials on CSS grids. It was my starting point too when I was just learning CSS grids. So, it seems you haven't followed their tutorials or other tutorials as you should because you did things that I believe the tutorials would teach you not to do. Now lets break down what I mean by that.

First, the reason why CSS grids exist is NOT for you to still use `display: inline-block` or `float` on the elements you already positioned or want to position with `display: grid;`. I'm talking about this specific line:

```
    table {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    form {
        display:inline-block;
        float:right;
    }
```

You used `inline-block` and `float` on the form and table, which are the elements you're trying to position with `display-grid`. That's not the goal. You need to stick with one. Either position them with display grid only, or use display inline-block. Even though you didn't really give display-grid on them, but these are the same elements that you will eventually assign the grid-area property after giving the display: grid to their parents.

so with that being said, here are the changes:
First I commented them out and instead used their wrapper divs to position them. By wrapper divs, I mean the div that you created with the `class ="forms"` and `class="tables"`. Also, instead of giving `display:grid` to the body, I instead gave it to you `gridcontainer div`, which you created and again did not use. 
Lastly, I also put the caption that is outside you tables div to be inside it because captions tag must be inserted immediately after the table tag. In short, compare the code bellow with the one you have to understand the changes I made and again, watch and read tutorials. Even w3schools that you mentioned as being the source you are learning css grids from explains enough for you to be able to achieve the tasks you wanted. And don't stop there. Keep learning other tutorials as well and happy coding. Here is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
    .gridcontainer {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'schedule info-table';
    /*
    grid-template: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    */
    }

    table,td,th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    th {
        background-color:black;
        color:white;
        font-family:verdana;
    }
    .time {
        background-color:#D3D3D3
    }
    .button {
        border:0;
        background:transparent;
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-weight:bold;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    td {
        font-family:Calibri;
    }
    /*
    table {
        display:inline-block;
    }
   */
   /*
    form {
        display:inline-block;
        float:right;
    }
    */
    .tables {
        grid-area: schedule;
    }
    .forms {
         grid-area: info-table;   
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 80vh;

    }

    table {
       height: 70vh; 
       width: 100%;
    }
    h1 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
    }

    caption {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    </style>
 </head>
 <body>

<header>
    <h1> Soccer Camp Registration</h1>
</header>

<div class="gridcontainer">
    <!--Did not understand why you need this, so I just commented it out. Also, 
    the colspan was throwing sintax errors. Check it!!!!-->
    <!--
<colgroup>
<col class="times">
<colspan="7">
</colgroup>
-->
    <div class="tables">
        <table>
            <tr class="days">
                <th></th>
                <th>Sun</th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Thu</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">9:00 am-10:30am</td>
                <td>Free Time</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Technical Skills</td>
                <td colspan="4">Training Session</td>
                <td>Free Time</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">10:30 am-12:00pm</td>
                <td rowspan="3">Round Robin Games</td>
                <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">Dribbling</td>
                <td rowspan="2">Game Analysis</td>
                <td> Agility</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">1:00pm-2:30pm</td>
                <td>Strength Training</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">2:30pm-5:00pm</td>
                <td colspan="3">Nutrition</td>
                <td>Passing and Receiving</td>
                <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">Campers Choice</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="time">6:00pm-8:00pm</td>
                <td colspan="5"> Night Games</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <caption>July 2017 Weekly Schedule</caption>
    </div>
    <div class="forms">
        <form method="POST" 
    action="https://csunix.mohawkcollege.ca/tooltime/showit.pl">
            <h2> Request Camp Information</h2>
            <fieldset class="camplc">
                <legend for="camplc"> Camper Location</legend>
                <label for="province"> Province</label>
                <select name="province" id="province">
                    <option value="BC"> British Columbia</option>
                    <option value="ON">Ontario</option>
                    <option value="AB">ALberta</option>
                    <option value="QC">Quebec</option>
                    <option value="YK"> Yukon</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="campid">
                <legend for="campid"> Camper Identification</legend>
                <label for="firstname"> First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="fn">
                <br>
                <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="ln">
                <br>
                <label for="Gender">Gender</label>
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="male" id="male">
                <label for="male"> Male</label>
                <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="female" id="female">
                <label for="female">Female</label>
                <br>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" 
               placeholder="name@example.com">
                <br>
                <label for="age">Camper Age</label>
                <select name="age" form="age">
                    <option value="8">8-9</option>
                    <option value="10">10-12</option>
                    <option value="13">13-15</option>
                    <option value="16">16-19</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="info">
                <legend for="info"> Please Send me information about</legend>
                <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Camp Dates" id="cd">
                <label for="campdates"> Camp Dates</label>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Camp Fees" id="cf">
                <label for="campdates"> Camp Fees</label>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="infoa" value="Transportation" 
               id="tn">
                <label for="campdates">Transportation</label>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="questions">
                <legend for="questions"> Question?</legend>
                <textarea placeholder="Please enter any questions or comments 
            here" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Request Info" class="button">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear Form" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

   </html>
```

Here is the working link with the code on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPpXWM